# iphone : strange behaviour of labels

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

on `viewWillAppear`  i am trying to hide labels but is not getting hide here.what could be wrong?

```
In case when alertview is not being shown it is working fine with hide/unhide.but when alert is shown it is not working



- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {

        for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {

                switch (transaction.transactionState) {
                case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:

                    break;

                case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:

                    flgCheck = 1;
                    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"YES" forKey:@"IN_APP_PURCHASE"];
                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"ON" forKey:@"REMOVEADS"];


                    [appdelegate removeAdmob];

                    [self viewWillAppear:YES];


                    if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"FROMPOPUP"] isEqualToString:@"Done"])
                    {
                        UIAlertView *purchasedone = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enable Ads" message:@"You can Enable Ads from Settings Option" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                        [purchasedone show];
                        [purchasedone release];
                    }
  }                 
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {

        purchaseDone = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"IN_APP_PURCHASE"];
        if([purchaseDone isEqualToString:@"YES"])
        {
            lblinst.hidden=YES;
            lblremovead.enabled = YES;
            adSwitch.enabled = YES;
            btnUpgrade.enabled = NO;
            if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"REMOVEADS"] isEqualToString:@"ON"])
            {
                [adSwitch setOn:YES];
                [appdelegate removeAdmob];
            }
            else
            {
                [adSwitch setOn:NO];
                [appdelegate addAdmob];

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: is lblinst linked to an outlet?

Comment: yes all outlets are fine

Comment: There could be many different reasons this isn't working, can you be more specific. Try NSLog-ging in the if statements and see how far it gets, it may be that your if statments aren't working correctly. Lastly, if this doesn't work then you can always just use `[lblinst removeFromSuperview];` and then `[self.view addSubview:lblinst]` later

Comment: yes i have checked with nslog and if condition is going ok. let me try with removeFromSuperView. Actually it is working fine in case when alert is not being shown but alert is showing it is not hiding any thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that the condition `[purchaseDone isEqualToString:@"YES"]`  evaluate to `YES`,
It seem me the result is `NO`.

And you could check  with putting the NSLog's ,

```
if([purchaseDone isEqualToString:@"YES"])
{
   lblinst.hidden=YES;
   NSLog(@"true :: hide the label");
   ............
   ......
}
else
{
   NSLog(@"False :: Not hide the label");
}
```

Comment: it is string but i have given its valueas YES.does it take 'yes' as boolean itself?even it is going in viewwillappear as i debbug but does not affect labels

Comment: that's fine @Heena, You are using one of many approaches Just suggest you to debug your code and try to print the value of `purchaseDone` using NSLOg's ..

Comment: you could also use the other approaches like storing the `boolean` rather then a `NSString` . In this case you will need to compare the strings ..

Comment: initially it prints `purchaseDone` value as `(null)` and after that when nsuserdefault set it shows `YES`

Comment: NSString comparision could be a problem but still it is going in viewWillAppear debugging the code of hiding labels still not affecting

Comment: That's expected behavior.. Are you setting the property `hidden` to `NO` in your code for your label ?

Comment: @Heena let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2607/discussion-between-jhaliya-and-heena)

Comment: no i am not doing that.initially all are showing then once purchase done i am hiding that with hidden YES. even values with ENABLE are not working

Comment: It should work .. Anyway you could try with setting the `alpha` property to `0.0f` and `enable` to `NO` for your label instead of setting its `hidden` property ... `lblinst.alpha = 0.0f; lblinst.enable = NO; `

Comment: ok i will try with alpha.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `purchaseDone` seems to be an NSString. I assume that because you want to compare it to the NSString `@"YES"`.

If you declared the value for the key `@"IN_APP_PURCHASE"` as a boolean (in your settings bundle). Then comparing the Strings will never be true. Simply compare boolean values and it should work.